# vb.net database connection destroys windows form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hy,

i am using a Access DB connection in my Visual Studio 2015 project. Unfortunatly if the function is used my windows forms are not displayed correctly anymore in the debugging mode. If i don't use the DB connection everything works fine - i assume there is any mistake in my connection (string)?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Datenbank
    Private Const Provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    Public Sub InitDbParameter(ByRef Con As OleDbConnection, ByRef Cmd As OleDbCommand)
        Con.ConnectionString = Provider & "Data Source =" & Db
        Cmd.Connection = Con
    End Sub

 Public Sub FillDGVMitarbeiter(ByRef DGV As DataGridView)
        Dim Con As New OleDbConnection
        Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ID As String

        InitDbParameter(Con, Cmd)
        Con.Open()
        Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Mitarbeiter WHERE gelöscht= false;"

        Try
            Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
            DGV.RowCount = 0
            Do While Reader.Read = vbTrue
                i = DGV.RowCount
                With DGV
                    .RowCount = i + 1
                    .Item("MitarbeiterID", i).Value = Reader("ID").ToString
                    .Item("MAVorname", i).Value = Reader("Vorname").ToString
                    .Item("MANachname", i).Value = Reader("Nachname").ToString
                    .Item("MaKürzel", i).Value = Reader("MA_Kürzel").ToString
                    .Item("MaEintrittsdatum", i).Value = Mid(Reader("Eintrittsdatum").ToString, 1, 10)
                    .Item("MaAustrittsdatum", i).Value = Mid(Reader("Austrittsdatum").ToString, 1, 10)
                End With
            Loop
            Reader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try


        Con.Close()
    End Sub
```

[Application without DB connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb8Wa.png)

[Application with DB connection and destroyed Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYTSu.png)

Comment: Move the Try to above InitDbParameter so that you catch the exception if you can't open the database

Comment: I can open the database and get all the data i want - just the appearance of the Windows Form is not correct - as shown in the second picture

Comment: The database wont be the issue then. The issue is with the layout in your forms.

Comment: It's hard to see how you could get that result in the second screenshot simply by a coding bug. I suspect something else is happening - could even be your video driver etc.

Comment: But the issue only occures with the db connection. As long as i do not use the FILLDGVMitarbeiter function there is no layout problem

Comment: My guess is there is no layout issue because there is no data to layout. Try adding in sample data into the form instead of doing the database load. I suspect there's an exception happening somewhere in the painting/layout code but some sample data will make that clear.

Comment: Sample Data works fine... it has something to do with the connection. No matter if i use the data from the connection, as soon as Con.Open() is performed the problem occures.

Comment: There are simpler ways to populate a DGV from a DB query.  I cant make out very much in the images but I doubt it has to do with the connection `per se'`.  Is that method invoked from Form Load?  If so set a breakpoint on the last line in Form Load and see if it stops there.

Comment: I am open to any suggestions :) Yes it is called in the Form Load. Breakpoint stops at the end as it should